# Firebase + Permissions

Tags: android, permissions, firebase, admob, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just updated one app from Firebase 9.0.0 to Firebase 9.0.2.
I use messaging + ads.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2' 
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2"
```

Now a lot of unwanted permission have cropped up

```
android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

I didn't add those permissions anywhere, so they must be from Firebase.
I know my clients don't like these permissions, so I removed them with

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

My app still works, messaging and ads still work, still I'd like my suspicions confirmed.

Why does Firebase add those permissions and is it really ok to remove them like I did?

Comment: see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/CXgecSxgsRE

Comment: It is unlikely that those permissions were added by firebase, if you build an app with only firebase-messaging or only firebase-ads none of these permissions are added. Could you confirm that when you build your app with 9.0.0 these permissions are not there and then show up when you move to 9.0.2 (now 9.2.1)?

Comment: @ArthurThompson I cannot build with 9.0.0 anymore. That's why I updated the dependency. When I use 9.0.0 I get "  java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' ... ". But I now changed to 9.2.1, updated build tools and everything else and now it works again without a crash and the superfluous permissions have also vanished...

Comment: Cool glad you got things sorted. Firebase should never add those permissions.

Comment: I have run into a similar problem. I've added Firebase as follows: compile   'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0',     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.0',     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.6.0',     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'

and it added READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_PHONE_STATE, C2D_MESSAGE, RECEIVE permissions. 

I then used tools:node="remove" in manifest and that sorted the problem, but it does not seem correct to be removing permissions that a library adds. Any more suggestions?

Comment: This should be reported as a bug on Firebase. I've done just that. Will update with their response.

Comment: It has been fixed in [version 10.0.1](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases).

Comment: Thanks for the information. If you like you can post that as an answer and maybe explain how it was an error on their side and I will accept it.

Comment: Check my answer in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42648929/1106018
It may help you.

Comment: This is a Bug in Firebase, I think its resolved in 10.* versions

Answer (score 5):

This issue was fixed in 12.0.1. Source https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

> March 28, 2018 - Verison 12.0.1
>
> Issues fixed in 12.0.1:
>
> - Fixes issue that caused spurious Android lint errors claiming
>     GoogleSignIn and CredentialsClient were internal-only.
> - Adds missing
>     minSdkVersion in -license artifacts to prevent automatic inclusion of
>     READ_PHONE_STATE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions.
> - Restores
>     unique package names for runtime linked -license artifacts which
>     affected some build systems' (e.g. Ionic Pro) compatibility issues.
> - Restores some fields names that were obfuscated in 12.0.1, namely the
>     value() method of @PropertyName annotations in firebase-firestore and
>     firebase-database.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

these permissions are different they are not used in fcm.

**PHONE_STATE** permission to know current state of phone

and  **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** and **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**  to add and delete file in memory from your app, if you are not using any of these functionalities you can remove it.

Comment: How to remove those permissions from project if I seem it in Merge Manifest file ?

Comment: add permission with app:node="remove"

Comment: what are you talking about? what different firebase libs adds those permission (some issue with aar), check it youself